# SPP-C and HC-05 are they the same thing or something else?

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

I was actually thinking to buy a cheap HC-05 module while I was searching I found a similar (think so) [module](https://m.aliexpress.com/s/item/32616503772.html) It say it is a replace for HC modules.

Is it compatible with Arduino Nano and will it work same as the HC-05 module ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory they are the same and have the same capabilities. Practically they are not. With SPP-C you get twice the headache for half the price as for HC-05. In had to find it out the hard way [Sending data using Bluetooth SPP-C Module without a Breakout-Board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26873/sending-data-using-bluetooth-spp-c-module-without-a-breakout-board). I tried both SPP-C and HC-05 with and without breakout boards finding the same issues. So if you are willing to spend time, risk your project and save some money then use SPP-C. Otherwise use the well known HC-05.

Comment: What about using with a breakout board will it be easy ???

Comment: As I wrote, I tried both. But yes. They are supposed to work as a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both the SPP-C and HC-05 are compatible with the Arduino range, and they do work in pretty much the same manner!